# How to build Nuxt.js project using downloaded create-nuxt-app

Tags: npm, nuxt.js, create-nuxt-app

I downloaded the repository [nuxt/create-nuxt-app](https://github.com/nuxt/create-nuxt-app). Then I modified some codes.
I would like to build Nuxt.js project using this modified create-nuxt-app, not using release version.
How to build Nuxt.js project using downloaded create-nuxt-app

Comment: follow link below :-

https://nuxtjs.org/guide/installation/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am glad to inform you that the problem is now solved!

1. I uploaded the modified create-next-app to my Github account.
2. I executed this command:

```
npx github:my-github-account/create-nuxt-app my-app
```